# Prove that a subset is an interval.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I'm stuck on a homework question.

"Let $f :\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function and let $I$ be an interval in $\mathbb R$. Show that $f(I)$ is an interval."

What I've done so far is tried to prove that $f(I)$ is an interval by proving the interval is convex (by the completeness axiom). I then used the intermediate value theorem but I don't know where to go from there. 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbLm9.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(I)$ is not an interval. Then, there exist numbers $x<y<z$ such that $x, z \in f(I)$ but $y \notin f(I)$.

Note that if $x,z \in f(I)$, then there are $a,b \in I$ such that $x=f(a),z=f(b)$. Hence, $f(a)<y<f(b)$, and $f$ is continuous. By the intermediate value theorem, it follows that $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such  that $f(c) =y$. Since $I$ is an interval, for any $a,b \in I$, every point between $a$ and $b$ (and hence $c$) is in $I$. So, $y=f(c) \in f(I)$, this is a contradiction.

Hence, $f(I)$ is an interval.